# create a new tab with a specific URL and inject a script into the newly created tab's page

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

background.js:
...
chrome.tabs.create({ url: "https://sample-page/" }, function(tab) {
const tabId = tab.id;

```
    // Inject script into the newly created tab
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { file: "subContent.js" });
   
  });
```

got an error:

Error handling response: TypeError: chrome.tabs.executeScript is not a function

Comment: In ManifestV3 it's chrome.scripting.executeScript with a different syntax and its own permission.

Comment: Right,  I got the answer:

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:
`chrome.scripting.executeScript` for manifest 3

```js
// create a new tab page
chrome.tabs.create({ url: "https://specific-web/" }, function(tab) {       
    //Inject script into the newly created tab                 
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tab.id },
        function: injectFunction,
        args: [url]
    })
})

//fill the current field with the new link and automate submition
function injectFunction(args) {    
    // activeElement is where the cursor resides
    document.activeElement.value = args;     
    submiturl.submit(); 
}
```